# Add info where to discuss programming stuff

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

On Stack Overflow, if you ask a new Question you get that box at the right saying:

> ### How to Ask
>
> **Is your question about programming?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)** instead.

Here you should add, "If you want to discuss something then ask on xxx.stackexchange.com"

Comment: I was all hopeful (and a little guilty) there would actually *be* a `http://xxx.stackoverflow.com` site, but I was sorely disappointed.. What naughty info would be find there? Porn site source code discussions? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Probably something Bender would enjoy...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: No, porn site source code *questions*.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Touché!

Answer (score 6):

> Here you should add, if you want to discuss something then ask on xxx.stackoverflow.com

Discuss... what exactly? What is "xxx" supposed to represent? A placeholder, a variable, or a porn site?

We are not a forum network. We are a Q&A network. We don't "discuss". Unless you're talking about meta-discussions, which is... here, basically. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: There is chat..

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SamIam programmers is still for questions and answers, not discussions.  They're simply allowed to be subjective questions.

Comment: When i read "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed." i thought that with discussion general questions like, what Framework should i use if i want to do x. Or, why is he using X instead Y in this application? etc. are meant. I think stackoverflwo is about specific! problems and not "designing" problems. So I thought there must be a site to talk about more general/designing stuff. I probably just didn't read probably. I think programmer.stackexchange.com is what i mean. xxx = placeholder of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to discuss a topic, but don't have an actual question that you want to ask, then the appropriate place to go would be chat (of whatever site is relevant to your topic of discussion).  None of the actual sites allow discussions (although meta sites are a bit lenient about it, but that doesn't seem to be relevant to you).

The site was designed as a question and answer site, and it has taken a number of steps to specifically inhibit discussions taking place here.  The site owners simply felt that mixing questions and discussions make finding useful content harder, and there were already so many places that allowed discussions to take place.

If chat isn't the appropriate medium for you, then odds are you're better of going to a traditional forum or another site of some sort to hold your discussion.

As for whether chat should be mentioned on that page; I think that would be appropriate.